# Updating Nested Dictionary with for loop python

Tags: python

I am trying to update a nested dictionary within a for loop, but the final output seems to over writing the previous key values.

```
a = {}
b = {}
f=0
for x in range(3):
    a['test1'] = 1+f
    a['test2'] = 2+f
    a['test3'] = 3+f
    f = f+1
    b[f] = a

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: {'test1': 3, 'test2': 4, 'test3': 5}, 2: {'test1': 3, 'test2': 4, 'test3': 5}, 3: {'test1': 3, 'test2': 4, 'test3': 5}}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{1: {'test1': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': 3}, 2: {'test1': 2, 'test2': 3, 'test3': 4}, 3: {'test1': 3, 'test2': 4, 'test3': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `b[f]=a` you assign item `f` of dictionary `b` to dictionary `a`, so if you change the values of dictionary `a` then all elements of `b` will point to this modified `a`. Instead, try creating a new dictionary and updating the values of `b`:

```py
b = {}
f=0
for x in range(3):
    a = {}
    a['test1'] = 1+f
    a['test2'] = 2+f
    a['test3'] = 3+f
    f = f+1
    b[f] = a

print(b)
{1: {'test1': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': 3}, 2: {'test1': 2, 'test2': 3, 'test3': 4}, 3: {'test1': 3, 'test2': 4, 'test3': 5}}
```

Or you can try this one liner:

```py
b = {f:{'test{}'.format(i):i+f for i in range(1,4)} for f in range(1,4)}
print(b)
{1: {'test1': 2, 'test2': 3, 'test3': 4}, 2: {'test1': 3, 'test2': 4, 'test3': 5}, 3: {'test1': 4, 'test2': 5, 'test3': 6}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do

```
a = {}
b = {}

for f in range(3):
    a['test1'] = 1+f
    a['test2'] = 2+f
    a['test3'] = 3+f
    b[f] = a
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are mutable, so when a dictionary is assigned to another variable, a pointer is simply assigned rather than a copy of the original dictionary. If you change the original dictionary, you change any variables associated with the pointer to that dictionary. To avoid this, you simply need `b[f]=a.copy()` instead of `b[f]=a`. This is for a single level dictionary; for deeper levels you should use `copy.deepcopy`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

```
b = {}
f=0
for x in range(3):
#add the part below

    a = {}

################

    a['test1'] = 1+f
    a['test2'] = 2+f
    a['test3'] = 3+f
    f = f+1
    b[f] = a



print(b)
```

Including "a" outside the loop was updating its values on each iteration, resetting the value of an allows you to execute your code accordingly.